# If a visitor leaves before a requested page loads, does that count as a pageview?

Tags: google-analytics

If a visitor selects a page on my site to go to, but the page takes so long to load that the visitor gives up and leaves my site first, does the vistor's request for that page count as a pageview for that page?

Comment: Depends, if the ga script has been executed. Ensure GA must fire after DOM Load

Answer (score 0):

A page view won't be counted until the GA javascript tracking tag executes.  It is recommended that your page view tracking tag is placed right before the closing body tag so that it doesn't fire until the DOM elements above it are loaded.